# Login with Facebook Flow in REST (Express.js with TypeScript + Passport.js) - few questions

Tags: node.js, typescript, facebook, express, authentication

i have few questions about login with facebook flow in REST application. I use Passport.js, Express.js, Typeorm and TypeScript. I don't implement client site yet.

First i created facebook strategy and i get a profile information in this place in code, but i want to process profile (check, save and generate JWT) in controller by use service layer.

`passport.ts`

```js
const facebookStrategyCallback = async(accessToken: any, refreshToken: any, profile: any, done: any) => {
  // I can get and process profile here, but i want to do it in controller use only
  // service layer to check, save and generate JWT token.
  done(null, profile);
};
```

This is my controller with facebook route and callback route:

```js
facebookAuth = (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    passport.authenticate('facebook')(request, response, next);
  };

  facebookAuthCallback = (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        session: false,
        failureRedirect: '/authenticate/fail'
      }, (error, profile) => {
        // process profile here using service functions
        // But what do next?
      })(request, response, next);
  };
```

My flow for now is:

1. In client someone click to Login with Facebook (redirect to `localhost:8080/oauth2/facebook`)
2. User see facebook login form and fill it
3. User profile with query params CODE back to server site application `localhost:8080/oauth2/facebook/callback?Code={somecode}` (Is this correct way?)
   ...

And now what's next? What i should do with CODE get from (`/ouath2/facebook/callback?CODE={somecodehere}`). I can process profile save it into database, but how to back token to client? With redirect and query params? it's less security i guess.
Maybe i should set facebook callback url to `localhost:3000/facebook/callback` - but what i should do with this code from query params when i pass it back to server site?

Can someone write me a correct flow in REST application?

Comment: Hello, might I ask that all you need is a very simple "Login with Facebook" feature like getting their public profile data or maybe you will also need their personal access token to perform some sort of actions later on?

Comment: Hello @FelixFong i need only very simple data like email and name.

Comment: Might I suggest a solution from the awesome folks at Firebase? they offer a complete and easy to use SDK for social sign-in like Facebook another company.

For more read up, you can visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login

Comment: I don't want use firebase :( I want to implement facebook login myself.